# find exact value of $\sin(10^\circ)$

Tags: trigonometry

How we can find exact value of $\sin(10^\circ)$?

I tried trigonometric ways but I get this equation:
$\ 8y^3-6y+1=0$ and $y = \sin(10^\circ)$ and [all the roots are complex](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZeJC.png).

I saw the pages in site, but I can't find the solution.
Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method

Comment: Using the formula for $\sin(3\theta)$, we can get a cubic. That is likely how you got yours. But we end up with the *casus irreducibilis* case of the cubic, and there is no useful "algebraic" way to solve the equation.

Comment: To be more specific, there is no expression for $\sin(10^\circ)$ that uses the ordinary arithmetical operations and $n$-th roots ($n=2,3,4,5,\dots$)  of **real** numbers.

Comment: Have a look at http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi18.html

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37650/discussion-on-question-by-s-h-w-find-exact-value-of-sin10-circ).

Comment: S.H.W. WA (or any other CAS) outputs the roots using cubic roots of complex numbers. But to write down those cubic roots requires you to know the values of trig functions of some angle $\theta/3$, where $\theta$ is in some sense given. Basically it means that you are running in circles. There is a formula for $\sin 10^\circ$ in terms of cubic roots of complex numbers, but to calculate those cubic roots you need to know $\sin 10^\circ$. I guess this is more or less what André was telling.

Comment: It looks like there are [three real roots](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gFGp0.png).

Comment: A cubic polynomial with integer coefficients cannot have three complex roots. Did you mean to say "complicated"?

Answer (score -2):

Using **Precise-Rewritten method** for Sin 10∘, **Exact value** may be determined as follows:

+45..............45.....................+2

-22.5............22.5...................-2

-11.25............11.25................+2

-5.625............5.625................+2

+2.8125............8.4375............-2

+1.40625...........9.84375...........+2

+0.703125............10.546875........+2

-0.3515625..........10.1953125......-2

**Hint for table**: First column is half of earlier (called as **Central**) with sign towards target angle 10∘; second is cumulative of the first column; and the third is division of current Central with earlier Central.

If we follow above pattern infinitely, the sum will be 10. However, we can see the repeating pattern in third column (-2, +2, +2); hence this is indication for the exact value.

Now write the third column top-to-down approach as:$$+2\overline{-2+2+2} $$.

In the next step just replace 2 by  √(2; the result will be :
$$√(2 \overline{-√(2+√(2+√(2} $$.

Sin 10∘ will be half of this (closing brackets are collapsed by "]").
Therefore, Sin 10∘ = $$√(2 \overline{-√(2+√(2+√(2}]/2 $$

Above method is called as **Precise-Rewritten method**. You can find **exact trigonometric value** of all integer angles using this method.

I apologize above bad formatting, discourage to explain the details here.

**Source: Breaking Classical Rules in Trigonometry:Precise-Rewritten method, 2016**

**Request to the scholars**: You may assist to copy edit the main document of above method. I have not idea to formatting and use of mathematical tools at all. I cannot format as online forum requires formatting the mathematics. If someone assisted me for copy edit on Precise-Rewritten method (and other new methods), every scholar may know the new idea for new method for exact trigonometric values. My (Breaking Classical Rules in Trigonometry- Mission 2050) un-skill on mathematics formating discouraging me to expose all of those new idea.

Comment: I read your article (https://www.scribd.com/document/327973537/Breaking-Classical-Rules-One-Third-Angle-in-Trigonometry-New-method-for-Cubic-Equation#download)  , and it doesn't make sense.

Comment: I try to understand your solution but it was too hard to understand . and I found several problems in your article. Thank you

Comment: Of course this is hard> There are two reasons:

Comment: Of course, this is hard to understand. The reasons are two: first my skill to writing is awkward and second this is new method than classical system. Request to improve the language in the answer above.

Comment: Yes , that's right.

Comment: Request to the scholars: May you assist me to copy edit the main document of above method. I have not idea to formatting and use of mathematical tools at all. I cannot format as online forum requires formatting the mathematics. **If someone assisted** me for copy edit on Precise-Rewritten method (and other new methods), every scholar may know the new idea for new method for exact trigonometric values. My (Breaking Classical Rules in Trigonometry- Mission 2050) un-skill on mathematics formating discouraging me to expose all of those new idea.

Comment: As commented under your other [answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2003067/291201) too: *hard to tell, but are those infinitely nested radicals by any chance*? Please articulate your ideas in some notation that others can understand and follow, otherwise you are just posting noise.

Comment: @dxiv: Above method (making half from 45 and taking sign for √(2 in all cases) is equally applicable for all angles for exact nested radicals. In all integer angles, the process is same. My weakness is to expression and use of mathematical formatting. You are requested to format in eligible method (see 'Request to the Scholars' above).